# Missing "Host in the cloud" check box in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, azure, deployment

When creating a project, in the second window, "select a template" there is no "Microsoft Azure" window in the bottom right, with the check box "Host in the cloud". Looked for the Azure SDK in the web found only version VS 2015.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Azure section has been removed on Visual Studio 2017 project creation window. You can right click on project, click publish and then you can select publish to Azure.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/20348/aspnet-core-project-host-in-cloud-checkbox-is-miss.html